# Powershell compress archive

Tags: powershell

Hey guys I am trying to write a script that will grab network paths from CSV and compress individual files in those paths to zip and move them to destination naming them original filename.zip. I think I am close but not working. Can you check the script and see where I failed? Thanks a lot!

**EDIT Got it working with:

```
$Paths = Import-CSV “PATH” 
$Path = $Paths.path
$Files = Get-Childitem $Paths.path 
$Dest = "\\DESTPATH"
Foreach ($File in $Files) { Compress-Archive $Path\$File –DestinationPath $Dest\$File.zip -Verbose }
```

Now my issue is needing to verify the Hashes of the ZIP prior to moving it to destination path. Is this possible or am I better off using 3rd party software?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "Files" inside the foreach:

```
$Paths = Import-csv C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Desktop\csv.csv
$Files = $Paths.path
Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    Compress-Archive $File –DestinationPath "C:\users\vmsilvamolina\Desktop\$($file.split("\")[-1]).zip" -Verbose
}
```

Additionally, I added the split expression to select the name of the file only.

Comment: Hey Victor thank you for the reply. This still fails for me after creating a blank named ".zip" file from the first item found in the path. Shouldn't the -destinationpath be $file.zip if I want it to individually name .zip files after original file name?

Comment: I fixed the destination path value on the answer because the name was $files instead of $file. For me work perfect with a csv files with paths. Can you upload your csv file?

Comment: Got it working with updated script in OP. Would you know of any way to compare file hash of Zip created before and after move?

Comment: Found the command and I am able to generate hash. Any way to automate the comparison prior to completing job?